# How do I uncompress a file with lots of zeroes as a sparse file?

Tags: files, compression, disk-image, sparse-files

I have a compressed raw image of a very large hard drive created using `cat /dev/sdx | xz > image.xz`. However, the free space in the drive was zeroed before this operation, and the image consists mostly of zero bytes. What's the easiest way to extract this image as a sparse file, such that the blocks of zeroes do not take up any space?

Comment: Just FYI, that's a _useless use of cat_. You can get exactly the same behaviour with `xz < /dev/sdx > image.xz`.

Comment: When running as root, yes. I stripped as much irrelevant detail from the command as I could, perhaps too much; typically I use `sudo cat` to read something that requires root access, while still running the programs being piped into as ordinary user.

Answer (score 31):

Citing the `xz` manpage (which you really should consult with such questions), in which I very quickly searched for `sparse`:

> --no-sparse
> Disable  creation  of sparse files.  **By default, if decompressing into a regular file, xz tries to make the file sparse if the decompressed data contains long sequences of binary zeros**.  It also works when writing to standard output as long as standard output is connected to a regular file and certain additional conditions are met to make it safe.  Creating sparse files may save disk space and speed up the decompression by reducing the amount of disk I/O.

(emphasis mine)

So, you don't have to do anything; just decompress with the default `xz` tool.

Comment: One addendum: The filesystem you are decompressing to must support sparse files. Most widely used filesystems on popular UNIX-like systems do these days, but if extracting to, say, a flash drive or SD card you can’t count on the filesystem having proper support.

Comment: that's very true! But then "extract to a sparse file" simply can't work, no matter the method.

Answer (score 16):

The GNU, NetBSD and FreeBSD implementations of the `dd` command at least have a `conv=sparse`. Quoting the GNU `dd` manual:

> `sparse`
> Try to seek rather than write NUL output blocks.  On a file
> system that supports sparse files, this will create sparse
> output when extending the output file.  Be careful when using
> this conversion in conjunction with `conv=notrunc` or
> `oflag=append`.  With `conv=notrunc`, existing data in the
> output file corresponding to NUL blocks from the input, will
> be untouched.  With `oflag=append` the seeks performed will be
> ineffective.  Similarly, when the output is a device rather
> than a file, NUL input blocks are not copied, and therefore
> this conversion is most useful with virtual or pre zeroed
> devices.

So I would attempt

```
xz -dc < image.xz | dd of=image conv=sparse
```

Using `dd` in this way will work with any form of input (whether or not the first command could generate sparse files itself).

Comment: no sense in doing that. `xz` does that by itself.

Comment: Not only is there no sense in that, but if `conv=sparse` had any effect then the result would be wrong. `xz` needs to receive the full data in order to represent it in the compressed output (which it will do compactly).  If instead `dd` skipped all-zero regions then the original image could not be correctly reconstituted from the compressed file.  However, although the manual page is not specific about this, I am inclined to think that `conv=sparse` would have no effect when the output is connected to a pipe, which is unseekable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I read that `man` excerpt the other way, as in it modifies the way `dd` writes output: if `dd` gets a `NUL` input block, it doesn't `write()` it but just `lseek()`'s to the position the *next* block will be written to.  That should create a sparse file regardless of the input type as long as the output blocks align properly to filesystem blocks.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: `dd`'s output *isn't* connected to a pipe here; this answer is suggesting piping decompressed `xz` output (with literal zeros) into `dd of=image`, for dd to find the zeros and seek in the output `image` file it created.  This works in general, it's just not needed in this case because `xz` will do that itself when writing to a seekable file.  (Err, to one it created I guess, rather than its stdout on an already-existing file with possible non-zero contents)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, dd -conv=sparse and/or using gzip/pbzip/xz etc doesn't produce good results when using modern hardware such as SSD's and NVME's, as unallocated blocks will return random data, which cannot be compressed or converted using sparse.  I suggest using:

```
partclone.<fstype> -c -d -s /dev/<input> -o /path/to/<output>
```

This will consistently create the smallest files and be the fastest to create / restore.  You can then tack-on compression, CRC etc if you so choose.